# attaching multiple events to a button issue in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, internet-explorer-9

I am working on very old application designed in early 2000. The page work on IE9 perfectly but not on firefox. After a lot of digging I got one issue. I have reproduced that in this simple example.

```js
function bindEvent(el, eventName, eventHandler) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false);
  } else if (el.attachEvent) {
    el.attachEvent('on' + eventName, eventHandler);
  }
}

function fun() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("tt");
  bindEvent(ele, "click", one);
  bindEvent(ele, "click", two);
  bindEvent(ele, "click", three);

}

function one() {
  alert("1");
}

function two() {
  alert("2");
}

function three() {
  alert("3");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fun()">Bind</button>
<button id="tt" name="tt">Test</button>
```

I have written the custom bindevent function as `attachevent` not supported by non IE browser.

Clicking upon Bind button will bind three events to Test button. Now Clicking upon `Test` button the output is

IE:

3
2
1

Firefox

1
2
3

So is there any way I can ensure in both browser the execution order will be same

Comment: Use jQuery? It implements the event handlers internally, so it gets consistent order across all browsers.

Comment: No permission from client to use jquery on this page.Thats the problem

Comment: then you'll need to write your own custom event handling functions that implement the ordering you want. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quirk of IE8 event model. MSDN makes a remark on [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If you attach multiple functions to the same event on the same object, the functions are called in random order, immediately after the object's event handler is called.

I think you can overcome it by registering only one event handler instead of three.

```
function fun() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("tt");
  bindEvent(ele, "click", function() {
    one();
    two();
    three();
  });
}
```